# Python set isdst of datetime object

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, python-datetime

A UTC time without an offset

```
from datutil import parser, tz
time_dst_str = '2023-06-01T15:25:00Z'
time_dst = parser.parse(time_dst_str)
```

An offset separately, along with whether or not this timezone has daylight savings time

```
offset_str = '-7.00'
is_dst = True # or False
offset = float(offset_str)

time_dst_tz = time_dst.replace(tzinfo=tz.tzoffset(None, offset*60*60)
```

How can I set whether or not this timezone supports? I was also trying to find the current implementations of ZoneInfo classes to reference and maybe do my own implementation, but haven't had luck yet

Comment: "How can I set whether or not this timezone supports?" Can you rephrase this, I don't know if I follow

Comment: UTC offset ≠ time zone. And no, you do ***not*** want to roll your own datetime/timezone lib ;-)